# Equal on Linq query

Tags: linq

I have to compare the filesystementries from Directory with other files, but this linq query doesn't work, I don't really know why I'm getting no result from it.

```
List<string> exampleFiles= new List<string>();
exampleFiles.Add("Foo.jpg");
exampleFiles.Add("Bar.jpg");

string ImagesOnFileSystem = @"c:\test";

List<string> filesInDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(ImagesOnfileSystem);                

var result = (from imageOnFs in filesInDirectory 
              from exampleFile in exampleFiles
              where InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(imageOnFs, exampleFile)
              select imageOnFs)
             .Distinct()
             .ToList();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Could you advise me what's wrong in my query?
Thanks

Comment: Directory.GetFiles Method: "An array of the full names _(including paths)_ for the files in the specified directory."

Comment: The first step in the troubleshooting process is to figure out what `Directory.GetFiles()` is actually returning.  Dump that output somewhere and examine it.  Perhaps the filenames you expect aren't being returned, or maybe they are being returned with different casing (and string's `operator==` overload does a case-sensitive compare).

Comment: Hi, I changed my code above but I can't still find an error.

Answer (score 4):

GetFileName returns filename including the path of the specified directory. However you are comparing the this with list item which just contains the file name. Change the where condition to:

```
where Path.GetFileName(imageOnFs) == exampleFile
```